# newData_0 is not defined - JS

Tags: javascript

What is the reason of this error: *newData_0 is not defined ?*

**code**

```
for (y = 0; y < 2; y++) {
        var newData_i = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            newData_i.push(null);
        }
        newData_i;
    }

    chart1.addSeries('xxx', newData_0, { //error
    //stuff
    });
```

thanks

Comment: `newData_0` should be `newData_i`?

Comment: god, yes. Thanks. big mistake

Comment: @user455318: I've posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably meant to type `newData_i` instead.